# How this $\sum_{n=0}^m n^{\exp ( \tan (n\pi))}$ related to Hurwitz zeta function?

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function, zeta-functions

I have tried to get this partial sum $\sum_{n=0}^m n^{\exp ( \tan (n\pi))}$  , In the first I have tried instead of $n$ a fixed integer $k$ the series is diverge but the partial  sum give me affine function which is $k(m+1)$, But when I tried to take the sum as $\sum_{n=0}^m n^{\exp ( \tan (n\pi))}$  it were hard for me fo evaluation however , Wolfram alpha turned me [this result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28n%5E%28+exp%28tan+%28+pi+n%29%29%29%29%2C+n%3D0+to+infty+):$$\sum_{n=0}^m n^{\exp ( \tan (n\pi))}=-\zeta(-1,m+1)-\frac{1}{12}$$ related to [Hurwitz zeta](//mathworld.wolfram.com/HurwitzZetaFunction.html) function but I can't prove it ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not simplifying $ n^{\exp(\tan(n\pi))}= n $ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Ok, But when we simplify it we will not get the same partial sum we will get 0.5 m(m+1) no relation to Huwirtz zeta function ?

Comment: It should be equivalent - look at what the Hurwitz Zeta simplifies to for negative integer first argument.